# if size of array is greater than 1

Tags: php, arrays, sizeof

I have an end of a link set, but I only want a portion to be used UNLESS the size of an array is greater than 1.

```
$closeLink='</a>'.'<a target=&quot;_blank&quot; href="'.implode('" rel="lightbox['.
$post->ID.']" class="single_image" title="'.$lightHtml.'<br />&lt;a href=&quot;'.
$desclinkurl.'&quot;&gt;'.$desclink.'&lt;/a&gt;"></a><a href="',$custgalarr).'"
rel="lightbox['.$post->ID.']" class="single_image" title="'.$lightHtml.'<br />&lt;a 
target=&quot;_blank&quot; href=&quot;'.$desclinkurl.'&quot;&gt;'.$desclink.'&lt;/
a&gt;"></a>';
```

So everything after the part shown isolated below needs to only show if the size of the array $custgalarr is greater than 1:

```
$closeLink='</a>'
```

I figure I need to use something like this after the closing a tag

```
if (sizeof($custgalarr) > 1){
```

Help me out, thanks in advance!

Comment: What language? And could you format your code snippet so it isn't all on one line?

Comment: @thomas reformatted. and PHP. I am not very familiar with it, just trying to help out here at work to fix something while another person is on vacation for the week. Appreciate the help!

Comment: Can you use a ternary operator? `$closeLink = '</a>' . (count($custgalarr)>1 ? ...code above... : '');` ? **EDIT** Or `$closeLink = '</a>'; if(count($custgalarr)>1){ $closeLink .= ...code above...; }`

Comment: @livinzlife What is the actual problem youre having, ie what is the error message or in what way the result differs from the expected one?

Comment: @BradChristie Perfect, I was having a parse error, but your code did the trick. Thank you

Answer (score 38, accepted):

In PHP it's

```
if (count($custgalarr) > 1)
```

Answer (score 1):

in PHP:

```
count()
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.count.php

Comment: Well, it apears that [sizeof](http://fr.php.net/manual/en/function.sizeof.php) is alias for count so that's not the problem

Comment: If that array would be a size of 1, that would return true also

Answer (score -3):

```
<?php

function wordlength($txt, $limit)
{
   $words = explode(' ', $txt);
   foreach($words as $v)
   {
       if(strlen($v) > $limit)
       {
            return true;
       }
   }
   return false;
}

$txt = "1";

if(!wordlength($txt, 1))
{
    die("String is less than or equal to one.");
}

?>
```